# Saving the Response to a file and reading that file in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im getting a BSON response from the server.I want to save it to a file and read that file instead of directly reading the response.

This is the method where im getting the response

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{


   // NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" 
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
   // NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];



    [self readTillEOF];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [data length] - 3);
    NSData *refinedData = [data subdataWithRange:range];
    [delegate didRecieveTillEof:refinedData];
}
```

can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what type of response r u recieving?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : Take a look at [this](http://sptci.com/docs/ios/bson/) how to convert BSON into NSString

Check if u can convert your data into array or dictionary and that can be used for saving in document directory like [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html).